# Eclipse Plug-in activated when Eclipse launch an Exception

Tags: eclipse, exception, plugins, handler, activation

I want to create an Eclipse Plug-in that will be activated automatically when Eclipse launch an Exception (while a java program is running). How can I do this?

Then I need informations about the Exception launched (name, class, etc.). Which class/package can give me these informations?

Until now I created only eclipse plugin activated by button (simple AbstracHandler).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's possible for uncaught exceptions only using a non Eclipse specific normal Java mechanism: You can enable a global handler using [Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29).

That said, you might break existing behaviour of Eclipse by doing this.